# Export preg_match_all matches to csv file

Tags: php, regex, csv, preg-match-all, fgetcsv

I'm trying to export matches from preg_match_all to a csv file but am getting the following error:

```
Warning: fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given
```

This is the section of code I'm having issues with, how can I modify it so I am able to export the matches to a csv file?

```
preg_match_all($pattern, $pos, $matches);

$fp = fopen('data.csv', 'w');
foreach($matches[0] as $data){  
 fputcsv($fp,$data);
}
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: `$data` doesn't seem to be an array. Should it be one?

Comment: Yes it should be an array, that's the problem I am having, I need to loop through each element in the array and add it to the csv file and I'm too much of a noob to figure it out myself.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
preg_match_all($pattern, $pos, $matches);

$fp = fopen('data.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($fp,$matches[0]);
fclose($fp);
```

The second argument needs to be an array. instead of looping through the matches (an array) and adding them one at a time, just pass the entire matches array (`$matches[0]`)

Comment: That's one solution I had already tried, but it doesn't work either. All I get is an empty csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the structure of your string or the regular expression, this is just a *guess* but it looks like you may be wanting to use `PREG_SET_ORDER` to make the `$matches` array group by the matches, rather than the default `PREG_PATTERN_ORDER` which groups the resulting array based on the capturing groups in the pattern (the [documentation](http://php.net/preg_match_all) has examples).

```
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($matches as $match) {
    // Get rid of $match[0] (the overall match)
    unset($match[0]);
    // Write the captured groups to the CSV file
    fputcsv($fp, $match);
}
```

If that is not what you're after, more info is needed from yourself like the structure of the `$matches` array that you want, and/or the input (`$subject`) and expected output (an example of the CSV file).